# Is it permissible to join first 2 rakath of Esha Salat with the Taraweh Jamat and then continue on his own?

Tags: hadith, salat, taraweeh, jamaat, fard

If one misses his Esha Salat, is it permissible for him to perform the first two rakats of his Esha Salat with the Taraweh Jamat and then continue on his own?

Answer (score 2):

Yes brother this is what Sheikh Shafi'i, Ibn al-Mundhir said. Please check the link below:

http://islamqa.info/en/ref/79136

Also there is a Hadith about this:

> حَدَّثَنَا يَحْيَى بْنُ يَحْيَى، أَخْبَرَنَا هُشَيْمٌ، عَنْ مَنْصُورٍ،
>   عَنْ عَمْرِو بْنِ دِينَارٍ، عَنْ جَابِرِ بْنِ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ، أَنَّ
>   مُعَاذَ بْنَ جَبَلٍ، كَانَ يُصَلِّي مَعَ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه
>   وسلم الْعِشَاءَ الآخِرَةَ ثُمَّ يَرْجِعُ إِلَى قَوْمِهِ فَيُصَلِّي
>   بِهِمْ تِلْكَ الصَّلاَةَ ‏.‏
>
> Mu'adh b. Jabal said the night prayer with the Messenger of Allah (may
>   peace be upon him) and then returned to his people and then led them
>   in this prayer. <sub>[[Sahih Muslim/(36)
>   Chapter: Recitation During 'Isha](http://sunnah.com/muslim/4/204)]</sub>

Answer (score 1):

According to the Hanafi school, such a prayer would be invalid.  Prayer is by intention, so a follower can only perform *fard* prayer if the imam is leading *fard* prayer.

It would however be permissible to perform *sunnah* prayers behind a *tarawih* imam, since the intention of the imam is equal to or stronger than the intention of the follower (i.e. *nafl* < *sunnah* < *wajib* < *fard*).

Answer (score -1):

I am from Turkey . I have a lot of information about this topic but I don't know to transfer to you, exactly.

Messenger of Allah - Prophet Mohammed pray 8 rakath Taraweh but permitted untill 20 rakath.

Witr Salah is wajib at Hanafi school.

When aliving Prophet Mohammed , People pray at home . They come to mosque for Esha Salat and going home.

After Die of Prophet Mohammed , in period of Caliph Omer , People pray irregular type. Someone is here others like near because Prophet Mohammed don't pray with community the Taraweh Salah so people don't pray together untill Caliph Omer. 
Caliph Omer says I wish I can correct this people in organized with this salah. They come to mosque but they pray alone . This screen not good , they are irregular . Islam order be regular and stay together.

If u understand I will go on;

1-"Benden sonra benim sünnetimden ve raşit halifelerin sünnetinden ayrılmayın" (Tirmizî, İlim, 16; İbn Hanbel, IV, 126)

2-Teravih namazı hiç şüphesiz müekked bir sünnettir. Hz. Ömer, bu namazın cemaatle ve yirmi rekat kılınmasını şahsi bir ictihadı ile yapmadığı gibi, bir bid'at olarak da emretmemiştir. O, kendisinin bildiği şer'î bir esasa ve Hz. Muhammed (s.a.v)'in bir vasiyetine dayanarak böyle yapmıştır." (et-Tahtavî, Haşiye, 334)

3-Teravih namazı başladıktan sonra camiye gelen kimse önce yatsı namazını kılar, daha sonra teravih namazı için imama uyar. Çünkü teravih yatsı namazına tâbidir ve ondan önce kılınmaz. (bk. DİA İslam Ansiklopedisi, Teravih md.; Şamil İslam Ansiklopedisi, Teravih md.)

I can't translate exactly but I will try.

1-Prophet Mohammed said "After me , Don't left my sunnah and sunnah of caliph . you should follow Calips" (Abu Bakr Omar Osman Ali)
it can help to believe Caliph Omar favour.

2-Imam Hanafi said " Caliph Omar don't tell personal opinion. He stay rules of Islam. Taraweh don't pray before Esha Salah. If a person come to Mosque. Community pray with together and they are in Teraweh. This person primary pray Esha Salah. İf he finish Esha Salah then he can pray Teraweh.

like this If u don't understand You can send me message . My first writing in this website :)

Happy Ramadan brothers